# How to Upload to AWS S3 with Transfer Acceleration using Python BOTO

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto

How can I pass a Transfer Acceleration endpoint-url to the boto upload_file function while trying to upload a file to S3?

My current code is:

```
s3.Bucket(BUCKET).upload_file(filetoupload, pathnfilename, ExtraArgs={'ACL':'public-read'})
```

Answer (score 1):

You would provide it with when you created your [resource](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/core/session.html#boto3.session.Session.resource) object:

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3', endpoint_url="the_endpoint")
```